# (SwiftUI) OpenURLAction is ignored when Text is selectable

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui

I've faced an issue while trying to handle hyperlinks from SwiftUI `Text` view. If I make a `Text` selectable, hyperlinks are always treated by system ignoring `.environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction)`.

```swift
let attributedString = try! AttributedString(markdown: "Here's the link: [link](https://expample.com)")

...

Text(attributedString)
  .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction(handler: { url in
    .handled // works ✅
  }

Text(attributedString)
  .textSelection(.enabled)
  .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction(handler: { url in
    .handled // ignored ❌
  }
```

Is there a way to keep `Text` selectable while manually processing hyperlinks? My platform is macOS.

Comment: I get the exact opposite. When using `.textSelection(.enabled)` the link is actioned, but when that is missing or is `.textSelection(.disabled)` the link is not actioned.
 However, if I use `.systemAction` instead of `.handled` and without using `.textSelection(.enabled)`, then the link is actioned.
 On MacOS 14 using Xcode 15, tested on MacOS 14. It could be different on older systems. So use `.systemAction` for your first `Text(attributedString)`

Comment: I get the same behaviour as OP on macOS 13.4 with Xcode 14.3.1.

Comment: Getting the same behavior on macOS 14.0 with Xcode 15.0.

Comment: I am also seeing this bug on macOS 13.6 + Xcode 15